# Is there a way to avoid/restrict starting a trial subscription without entering payment details in stripe?

Tags: stripe-payments

Is it possible to create a trial subscription only when the user enters their payment details(card). It looks like by default stripe allows starting the trial subscription without the payment details.

the current payment process is as follows

**step one**: user has to pick the payment plan (which includes a trial period) - In this step it calls the backend to create a customer and a subscription in stripe

**step two**: enter payment details (with setup intent)

This works well but if the user closes the browser or cancels without entering card details on the stripe side the status is still "trialing".

Is there a way I can restrict the trial subscription without payment details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. To start trial subscription only with payment information collected, you can swap Step 1 and 2. For instance,

1. Collect payment information using SetupIntent: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse
2. Pass payment method ID (`pm_xxx`) created in Step 1 as “default_payment_method” when creating a trial subscription: https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create#create_subscription-default_payment_method

If payment information collection is not done in Step 1, subscription shouldn’t be created in Step 2. This will ensure trial subscription always has a default payment method attached.

Alternatively, you can use Checkout Session to create a trial subscription. Subscription is only created after payment method is collected: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/quickstart